# how to get diameter of a object in a image?

Tags: python, image-processing, object-detection, scikit-image

I have build a basic object detection using scikit-image processing tool and I've provided an example below with an example image. I've also provided the example output below.

I want to find the diameter of the objects detected? Can any one explain how can I achieve this?

I found there are multiple attributes available for [`regionprop`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html#skimage.measure.regionprops) function in [`scikit-image`](https://scikit-image.org/) but I couldn't figure out how to find diameter of the object?

I am doing this on another real image but I've using almost similar code and was wondering if someone could help me out here. Thanks a lot.

Note: I've found this tutorial in the documentation regarding measuring region properties from this [`link`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/segmentation/plot_regionprops.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-segmentation-plot-regionprops-py) but I was not able to understand on how to use this to get diameter of the objected detected.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

from skimage import data
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.segmentation import clear_border
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops
from skimage.morphology import closing, square
from skimage.color import label2rgb


image = data.coins()[50:-50, 50:-50]

# apply threshold
thresh = threshold_otsu(image)
bw = closing(image > thresh, square(3))

# remove artifacts connected to image border
cleared = clear_border(bw)

# label image regions
label_image = label(cleared)
image_label_overlay = label2rgb(label_image, image=image)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.imshow(image_label_overlay)

for region in regionprops(label_image):
    # take regions with large enough areas
    if region.area >= 100:
        # draw rectangle around segmented coins
        minr, minc, maxr, maxc = region.bbox
        rect = mpatches.Rectangle((minc, minr), maxc - minc, maxr - minr,
                                  fill=False, edgecolor='red', linewidth=2)
        ax.add_patch(rect)

ax.set_axis_off()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This code returns this,

[`OUTPUT`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq19k.jpg)

Comment: You might find this blog post interesting: https://www.crisluengo.net/archives/408 -- It shows MATLAB code, but you should be able to translate that to Python quite easily. The method is implemented in Python in the [DIPlib project](https://github.com/DIPlib/diplib).

Comment: Also, `regionprops` returns `equivalent_diameter`, which is not exactly the diameter but would be a good approximation for your almost-circular objects.

Comment: @CrisLuengo This is the output image of my original ouput image --> [`TMT Rod`](https://pasteboard.co/ICAG7zH.png). These rods are 9-13mm in diameter and I want to calculate it's diameter. And `equivalent_diameter` is returning a value which is not making much sense. Is it possible to convert it to `mm` representation?

Comment: That's a very different image from what you posted in your question. Here the diameter of the rods should be obtained from the width of the box. The `equivalent_diameter` will not be meaningful (it is the diameter of the disk with the same area as your object). All measures are, I assume, returned in pixels. You need to know the number of mm per pixel, and multiply your measurement in pixels with that value.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I'm sorry for providing different example output image. I just thought If anyone could help me with that example image then I could transfer that to my original image output.  So how can I know number of mm per pixel in this case as each rod in the image has different width? Here in my case there isn't a default correct value as each rod in the image has different width. Is there any other way to infer width from the bounding box/pixels?

Comment: What do you mean? If you want to measure something with a camera, you need to calibrate your system and know how many pixels an object of a certain size occupies in the image. You need to keep the system consistent such that all images are taken in exactly the same way (so two objects of the same physical size occupy the same number of pixels), or you need to include a ruler in each of the images you take. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) You cannot guess the size of an object without the calibration. An image is a 2D projection of a 3D scene, a large object far away or a small one close by appear the same way in the image and you can't tell those situations apart without a calibration.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Are you saying that it's not possible to get width from the objects recognized in my image output? It's like you mentioned we only need width of each object in the bounding box In this case? Even a approximate estimate will also be good enough for my usecase?

Comment: There's no way to tell how large an object is if you don't have a calibration. A camera does not provide depth information, so you don't know how far away an object is from the camera, so you don't know what the magnification is.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Is it possible to find diameter if we train a object detection model using deep learning models and annotate each image with diameter of those rods and then predict it on a new image?

Comment: No. A large object far away looks identical to a small object close by. You cannot do this. You need calibration.

Comment: Look at this trick here: https://youtu.be/XXaVwItbPcY?t=16 -- Did it fool you? That proves the point that you cannot tell how large something is in an image.